# Who else out there is using the Facebooker plugin for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebooker

I've been working with the plugin for a couple weeks. Any other SOers using it, and if so, is there any knowledge or wisdom you've gleaned from using the plugin/gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used it this past week, but only for some basic functionality like retrieving a user's status updates. As a beginner, I really like how straightforward it was to implement in my app, and it helped me to better understand the facebook api in general.